# Android intent filter not restricting app to handle only YouTube links

Tags: android, share, intentfilter

I'm trying to restrict my Android app to handle only YouTube links when sharing content.

I've set up an intent filter in my AndroidManifest.xml file as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/*" android:host="youtu.be" android:pathPattern="/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, even after specifying the host and path pattern, my app still shows up in the share list for all types of URLs, not just YouTube links. I want my app to only appear in the share list when sharing YouTube video links.

Is there something I'm missing or any additional configuration needed to achieve this restriction? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACTION_SEND` does not use a URL, so `android:host` and `android:pathPattern` will be ignored.

> my app still shows up in the share list for all types of URLs, not just YouTube links

There is no option with `ACTION_SEND` to filter on the content of the text being shared.

You could switch to `ACTION_VIEW`, remove `android:mimeType`, and add `android:scheme="https"`, but that might not show up in the menus that you are seeking.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, if I understand correctly, it seems there isn't a direct method to restrict my app's visibility in the share menu to only YouTube URLs. I appreciate your assistance in clarifying this matter.